# WPF Prism MVVM - highlighting grid cells on the view from view-model rules?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

Suppose I have a grid control be it the plain WPF grid or a DevExpress grid or other, which is databound to a collection of financial positions that refreshes every set interval (like say, 2-3 seconds). I'm still relatively new to Prism and WPF in general

Because view-models shouldn't make any assumptions about the view it's tied to, and thus even assume there's a grid, how would I implement multiple rules where say, I wanted a cell to highlight in the grid according to some criteria based on other values in the same row? (eg if x > a + b for a row)

Or maybe something more complex like call some sort of calculation method on the View-Model to obtain the desired criteria? (otherwise I could just use a data trigger for that first example)

How would I design this and expose this behavior from the view-model and how would I set up the binding expressions on the view so that they automatically re-evaluate and update themselves each tick? (without slow down)

Comment: You can use a data trigger for both examples...You can expose a property that your row can bind to that either calls a method or runs a calculation of other properties. You can then call PropertyChanged on this property and your row will update according to your view logic...as for the "no slow down", doing it this way is going to depend on the calculations being run

Comment: Great and the triggers would be setup as Styles in the view's resources typed on the underlying object, right? What happens if the grid is bound to an ObservableCollection<T> where the underlying objects don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: 1) The style would be typed on your GridRow (if that's the control whose property you want to change) and 2) It might be wise to write a wrapper for T that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and bind your ObservableCollection to that new class.

Comment: Gotcha - so basically the grid can only figure out the underlying data has changed, and thus apply the high-lighting via the data-trigger, if it the underlying bound object supports a change-notification interface provided through a setter raising PropertyChanged? (can you put this as an Answer so I can give you credit)

Comment: Sure...Just keep in mind you this property doesn't necessarily have to have a setter. It can be read-only, with just a getter, and your PropertyChanged notification can come from anywhere in the code.

Comment: Oh that's a good point I didn't realize - I was actually thinking, in a worse case scenario if you had n rows with m columns, in a worst case scenario each column could change value and thus require a PropertyChanged event called n x m times ..instead I could have an IsDirty flag and instead call PropertyChanged once for each row?

Comment: Try some things. If you get results that are acceptable time-wise, then worry about re-factoring later. If performance is poor, then we can rethink the strategy. Adding some code to your question would help also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a data trigger for both examples...You can expose a property that your row can bind to that either calls a method or runs a calculation of other properties. You can then call PropertyChanged on this property and your row will update according to your view logic...as for the "no slow down", doing it this way is going to depend on the calculations being run